# ¿Cómo Iterar una tabla en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, tablas

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
let tab = document.getElementById("tabla");

for (let i = 0, row; row = tab.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (let j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        console.log(cell.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Bien, esto me itera todas las celdas td de una tabla html.

El problema es que no consigo indicarle que solo me muestre una fila o varias, según quiera indicarle.

La tabla es de 5x5.

Quiero hacer dos cosas:
-Sacar únicamente una fila, por ejemplo la 3.
-Aparte (no en el mismo bucle) quiero obtener una columna, por ejemplo, la 2.

Comment: ¿Sería correcto poner un if con un break? Es decir, dejarlo todo tal cual y decirle, por ejemplo, if (i > 3) {
            break;
 }

Comment: Esto funciona, pero no sé si hay una forma mejor de hacer esto.

Comment: Si solo quieres una única fila... para qué usas un bucle anidado? Utiliza un único bucle directamente en la fila que quieres: `tab.rows[2].cells[j]`. Lo correcto sería meter ese 2 en una variable si vas a calcularlo de alguna manera, pero si quieres acceder siempre a la misma... pues *hardcodealo* ahí y listo, no necesitas un bucle que realmente no va a recorrer nada :)

Comment: Quiero el bucle para poder indicar si quiero una o varias filas. Edito la pregunta para expresarlo bien.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo para aprender bien a manejar una tabla con bucles. Es solo práctica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes "sacar" el bucle interno a una función, algo como esto:

```javascript
let tab = document.getElementById("tabla");

    for (let i = 0, row; row = tab.rows[i]; i++) {
        showRow(row);
    }

    function showRow(row) {
      for (let j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        console.log(cell.innerHTML);
      }
    }
```

Por tanto, si sólo quieres sacar una fila en concreto, puedes llamar a

```
showRow(tab.rows[numeroDeFila]);
```

Ejemplo:

```js
let tab = document.getElementById("tabla");

//recordemos que el índice empieza en 0, por lo que la fila 3 es la cuarta
console.log("Fila:");
showRow(tab, 3);
console.log("Columna:");
showColumn(tab, 1);


function showRow(table,rowNumber) {
  //con esto obtenemos un array (iterable) de celdas
  const row = Array.from(table.rows[rowNumber].cells);
  //bucle for para recorrer iterables
  for (const cell of row) {
    console.log(cell.innerHTML);
  }
}

function showColumn(table, columnNumber) {
  for (let i = 0, cell; i < table.rows.length;  i++) {
    // no hay "columnas" en table, no podemos crear un iterable
    // tan elegante como en showRow
    const cell = table.rows[i].cells[columnNumber]
    console.log(cell.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id= "tabla">
  <tr>
   <td> celda11 </td><td> celda21 </td><td> celda31 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> celda12 </td><td> celda22 </td><td> celda32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> celda13 </td><td> celda23 </td><td> celda33 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> celda14 </td><td> celda24 </td><td> celda34 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> celda15 </td><td> celda25 </td><td> celda35 </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Excelente solución. Ya sé que es mucho pedir, pero ¿cómo se podría adaptar esto para obtener una columna?

Comment: En este caso, creo que necesitaría un bucle anidado. Primero, que itere cada una de las filas y después, que obtenga solo la celda x de cada fila, obteneiendo así la columna. Voy a ver si lo puedo realizar.

Comment: Te lo he añadido, mejorando un poco el código anterior

Answer (score -1):

En verdad, lo he conseguido así: Le digo que i = 3 y con un if, le digo que salga cuando sea mayor que 3.

```
let tab = document.getElementById("tabla");

for (let i = 3, row; row = tab.rows[i]; i++) {
     if (i > 3) {
        break;
    }
    for (let j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        console.log(cell.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

¿Diríais que es la mejor forma?

Si quiero dos filas, me bastará con cambiar los números:

```
let tab = document.getElementById("tabla");

for (let i = 0, row; row = tab.rows[i]; i++) {
     if (i > 2) {
        break;
    }
    for (let j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        console.log(cell.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: No me parece la mejor solución, realmente te sobra el bucle externo. Te he puesto una forma más clara de verlo en mi respuesta